# Create a 2 tone (or 2 colour) border on a style in Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am trying to create a two tone border to go under headings in MS office. The goal is to look like this one:

[image]

Notice how the Heading has an underline with two colours (of different sizes as well). This is easy enough to do in CSS, which was

```
#element-id{
  border:yellow 3px solid;
  box-shadow:0 1px 0 dark-yellow;
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I would be happy to use an image as the border as well. This will be used a template for all Word documents, so I will have to be able to embed this style into a Word Template.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it completely within Word would be to first insert an "Autoshapes" drawing canvas picture beneath the title words in the document's header, and then drawing two horizontal lines next to one other of different colors and widths on the canvas. You can set the color and linewidth by right-clicking on each and selecting "**Format Autoshape...**".

Here is what it would look like in Word like immediately following creation:

[image: Screenshot of sample document in Word]

You can download the above sample Word document [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5508445/superuser/2%20Tone%20Word%20Header.doc).

A slightly different approach would be to create a simple image file with an external app and then insert it as a Picture element into the Word document's header. After inserting it you can resize it as necessary. On Windows the image file could be created with the provided Paint application.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to make part of the style, say every h2 or h3 tag? I am making a template and every time a user clicks h2, I want this two tone line below it.

Comment: @Kelly: I don't know of a way to make it part of a style, which are for applying formatting, not providing content (unlike a document's header).